# Why is probability theory that important to communication theory?

Tags: communication, digital-communications

Since Shannon's paper *Mathematical theory of communications*, probability theory has played an important role on communications (digital and analog).

I've been checking some course descriptions on my college and noted that for almost every course related with communications an important prerequisite is probability.

Why is that? What is the role of probability in communications? Is it a practical approach or just theoretical?

Comment: Communication is inescapably plagued by noise. Noise is instantaneously unpredictable, but globally quantifiable. And the tool for modeling such processes is ... probability and stats.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In analog communications, you are trying to recover a message signal from a received signal containing noise. Noise is a random fluctuation of the signal variable. So with out some theory of what *random* means, we can't even understand what noise is.

Furthermore when we talk about recovering the message signal, we're basically talking about *estimating* the original signal from the received signal (corrupted by noise). Again, estimation is a fundamental of probability theory.

In digital communications, at the most basic level, we talk about receiving bits of a message after they pass through a channel with some probability of error. Again, this description doesn't even have meaning until we have a theory of probability.

Comment: Taking things a little further, when transmitting data by radio, there is almost always a significant probability that any particular piece of a transmission will be garbled.  For communication to be reliable, it must be robust against such corruption.  Transmitting something 100 times might make it somewhat robust, but would reduce bandwidth by a factor of 100.  Using other means of forward error correction might offer even more robustness with less bandwidth; if one can use retransmission-based error correction, one might do better yet.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, probability theory matters since it is used to model phenomena (e.g. noise, interference, fading etc...), which follow known statistical distributions., in communication systems - specially when we're considering complex systems (e.g. cellphones/wireless networks in a large city).

E.g. the effects of propagation upon a radio signal can be modeled as [Rayleigh fading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_fading).